# How to identify the SharePoint exception when trying to create a new site

Tags: sharepoint, exception, spsite

Ok,

This seems stupid but I figured I would ask because there is a lot of expertise to tap into here and I will probably learn a good bit from the answers.

I have a service center panel for creating sites. If site creation fails, I would like to delete the site. EXCEPT if the exception is because another site already exists at that URL.

I currently get the following and could easily check for contained text but would like a more solid approach. (e.g. looking for an exception ID or something to this effect.)

> Another site already exists at http://server:80/sites/xxxxxxxx. Delete
>   this site before attempting to create a new site with the same URL,
>   choose a new URL, or create a new inclusion at the path you originally
>   specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you check to see if the site exists first before trying to create it?

Comment: Thought about this but that means another try/catch and potentially false positives in case creating the SPSite object to check if it exist throws an exception.

Comment: This really is the only way to do it. You can catch the other exception and check the Message property but other than that, there is no way to check against a unique exception ID.

Answer (score 1):

As TrovB30 says, checking if it exists before trying to create is probably the best way of doing that.

I assume you have a reference to a SPSiteCollection object or a SPWebApplication object? In that case I would probably loop through it to see if there already exists one. This may seem tedious but will probably be more efficient than a try-catch procedure:

```
private bool SiteExists(SPWebApplication webApp, string siteUrl)
    {            
        var sites = webApp.Sites;
        //Add slash to enable comparison
        siteUrl = "/" + siteUrl;
        foreach (SPSite site in sites)
        {
            if (site.ServerRelativeUrl.Equals(siteUrl) == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```